# pip - install matplotlib in virtualenv

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I want to install matplotlib to virtualenv using pip. (pip 7.1.0, python 3.4)

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install matplotlib

...
REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.9.2]
                   six: yes [using six version 1.9.0]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.4.2]
                  pytz: yes [using pytz version 2015.4]
               tornado: yes [using tornado version 4.2.1]
             pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.0.3]
                 pycxx: yes [Official versions of PyCXX are not compatible
                        with matplotlib on Python 3.x, since they lack
                        support for the buffer object.  Using local copy]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
```

I managed to install most of the dependencies, but `pycxx` and `libaag` fails with similar error:

```
Collecting pycxx
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pycxx (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pycxx
```

My question is: What did I do wrong? Is there some workaround?

I could (maybe) install matplotlib using distro package manager and then import it somehow to virtualenv - that's where I would need a help.

Comment: side note. If you are on windows you can use pip to install binaries found from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. Once you have the file downloaded activate your virtual environment in the console and ''pip install path_to_downloaded_file/matplotlib‑1.4.3‑cp35‑none‑win32.whl. If it errors it should tell you what requirment library that it couldn't install, so install that library the same way first.

Comment: @HashSplat I'm on linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you got numpy and scipy installed already in the venv ? I had some installation issues for numpy, scipy and matplotlib and upgrading pip and setuptools within the enviroment fixed everything:

```
$ pip install -U pip
$ pip install -U setuptools
```

If you install matplotlib using a package manageer you can just do the following when setting up your venv:

```
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages myvenv
```

And that should get matplotlib in to myvenv

Comment: I do have numpy. Scipy fails to install with "Command .... failed with error code 1 ..." :( I did the update.

Comment: Guess the `--system-site-packages` it is :/

Comment: I had some issues installing these in virtualenv but all I had to do was upgrade or install things like gfortran on my machine. The specific error might let you know what packages are missing.

Comment: [My response on this thread may help some](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33509933/3321542).

Comment: The update of pip and setuptools also solves the issue "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)" while installing `pip install matplotlib` inside your venv